# Package biblatex Warning: citation '' was not found at all in the .bbl, bibliography labels cannot be generated

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is the package I am using to cite in my master thesis and the error that's occurring is the one displayed in the title. I don't understand where this error is coming from. If you need to see any more of the code for a solution just let me know. I'm happy for any help! Thanks a lot for trying to solve my problem.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{Literaturliste.bib} 
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=999, 
maxcitenames=1, 
backref=false, 
bibencoding=utf8, 
defernumbers=true}
```

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864? For help on getting your editor to run Biber please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If you successfully ran Biber you should be able to find a `.blg` file (on Windows the `.blg` file may be classified as a 'Performance Monitor' file, but it is still a plain text file that you can open with your favourite text editor), please post its complete contents here.

Comment: Any news here? Did you make sure to run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX on your document?

Comment: Any news here? As the question stands now our best guess is that it is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If there are no new developments here in due time I will vote to close this question as unclear (of course I will immediately vote to reopen if something new emerges).

Comment: I voted to close your question as duplicate of our standard question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. At this point in time, this is the best we can do.If running Biber does not work for you, please update your question with more details.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't answer for so long. First it did work again (there seemed to be a problem with the available space). But now I get the same problem again. There is no output .blg file and the citation ist not working. I did run Biber as explained. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: If there is no `.blg` file that strongly suggests that you did not run Biber or that there was such a fatal error that Biber had to abort immediately even without writing a `.blg` (the latter option is quite unlikely). On Windows PCs the `.blg` file might be classified as a 'performance monitor file', it might be easier to find the files if you display file extensions, - the files written by Biber, however, are just simple plain text files that you can open with your favourite text editor. Double check that your Biber configurations are OK. ...

Comment: ... If you are still having problems ask a *new* question with a short example document (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and share as much information about what you are doing to compile and what output you are seeing as possible.